# Attach custom css library to entity print output

Tags: 8, theming

I need to attach custom css library so entity_print module uses it to generate the final PDF.

The goal is to get custom css effect the generated PDF at  `/print/pdf/node/{{NID}}`

I have set the PDF engine to mpdf under entity print configuration

I tried the following 2 methods unsuccessfully :

1. Attach to node.html.twig file using `{{attach_library('THEMENAME/library_name')}}`
2. Attach it to `entity_print` at `THEMENAME.info.yml` file per described at https://www.drupal.org/node/2706755

I don't see the attached css at `/print/pdf/node/{{NID}}/debug` when inspecting elements

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question for the ones who might probably face similar issues.

The 2nd method as described at https://www.drupal.org/node/2706755 where we attach the library to `entity_print` works.

I had a custom `entity-print--node.html.twig` in which I **missed** printing the css styles using the variable `{{ entity_print_css }}`